# use windows command to extend displays

Tags: c#, winforms, shell

Im trying to execute command based on this thread:
[Run Command Prompt Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)

Im using this code:

```
   private string cmdForDuplicate = @"C:\Windows\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe \clone";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private string cmdForExtend = @"C:\Windows\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe /extend";

    private void btn_extend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

        startinfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        startinfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32\DisplaySwitch";
        startinfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";
        startinfo.Verb = "runas";
        startinfo.Arguments = "/c" + cmdForExtend;

        Process.Start(startinfo);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is not working? What is the error you get?

Comment: No Error, just command does not work

Comment: Try removing :  startinfo.Verb = "runas";  You may not have the privilege to run at higher level.

Comment: I used another directory, because system32 does not work I have DisplaySwitch.exe file and I want to work it as extend, what should I do?